# How to logically subtract rows

Tags: r

my df look kind of like this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  "id" = c(2, 4, 5), 
  "paid" = c(80, 293.64, 157),
  "basic_fee" = c(500, 140.59, 21.49),
  "marketing_fee" = c(151.51, 10.12, 562.50),
  "utility_fee" = c(65, 99.29, 102.35),
stringsAsFactors = F)
```

What I'd like to achieve is this

```
final <- data.frame(
    "id" = c(2, 4, 5), 
    "paid" = c(80, 293.64, 157),
    "basic_fee" = c(500, 140.59, 21.49),
    "marketing_fee" = c(151.51, 10.12, 562.50),
    "utility_fee" = c(65, 99.29, 102.35),
    "paid_basic" = c(80, 140.59, 21.49),
    "paid_marketing" = c(0, 10.12, 135.51),
    "paid_utlity" = c(0, 99.29, 0),
    stringsAsFactors = F)
```

The logic between that is quite simple actually. For each id get amount of paid value, then "pay as much possible" to fees with priority in order - basic, marketing, utility. Note that no fee can have paid amount higher that it is actual value.

My code bellow works but it is very ugly with lot for repeated code parts. Now I have even more complicated dataframe with 100+ columns. I don't wan't create code with still more and more complicated if elses with thousdands of rows.

```
final <- 
  data %>% 
  mutate(
    paid_basic = if_else(basic_fee - paid > 0, basic_fee - (basic_fee - paid), basic_fee),
    overpayment_basic = if_else(paid-paid_basic > 0, 1, 0),

    paid_marketing = if_else(overpayment_basic == 1, (paid-paid_basic), 0),
    paid_marketing = if_else(paid_marketing > marketing_fee, marketing_fee, paid_marketing),
    overpayment_marketing = if_else(paid-paid_basic-paid_marketing > 0, 1, 0),

    paid_utility = if_else(overpayment_marketing == 1, (paid-paid_basic-paid_marketing), 0),
    paid_utility = if_else(paid_utility > utility_fee, utility_fee, paid_utility)
)
```

Comment: As a start, your `paid_basic` definition can be simplified to `pmin(paid, basic_fee)`. The challenge will be applying this iteratively to subsequent columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is much less complex than your existing solution, but here's one way to get the additional columns

```
library(tidyverse)

fee_data <- select_at(data, vars(contains('fee')))

fee_data %>% 
  accumulate(`+`) %>% 
  map2_df(data$paid + fee_data, ~ .y - .x) %>% 
  map2_df(fee_data, ~ pmax(0, pmin(.x, .y))) %>% 
  rename_all(~ paste0('paid_', sub('_fee', '', .x))) %>% 
  bind_cols(data, .)

#   id   paid basic_fee marketing_fee utility_fee paid_basic paid_marketing paid_utility
# 1  2  80.00    500.00        151.51       65.00      80.00           0.00         0.00
# 2  4 293.64    140.59         10.12       99.29     140.59          10.12        99.29
# 3  5 157.00     21.49        562.50      102.35      21.49         135.51         0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

My original answer wasn't generalizable to an arbitrary number of rows, so here's another attempt:

```r
r <- data$paid # keep track of remaining money
select(data, ends_with("_fee")) %>%
    set_names(sub("(.*)_.*", "paid_\\1", names(.))) %>%
    mutate_all( ~ {`<-`(x, map2_dbl(., r, ~ pmin(.x, .y))); `<<-`(r, r-x); x}) %>%
    bind_cols(data, .)
```

Which returns:

```r
  id   paid basic_fee marketing_fee utility_fee paid_basic paid_marketing paid_utility
1  2  80.00    500.00        151.51       65.00      80.00           0.00         0.00
2  4 293.64    140.59         10.12       99.29     140.59          10.12        99.29
3  5 157.00     21.49        562.50      102.35      21.49         135.51         0.00
```

Instead of `mutate` I use `mutate_all` to apply `map2_dbl` with `pmin` to every column in the subset.

Comment: Yes, but this is also slightly less robust I believe. If you have fourth column will you add another layer of `ifelse` and what if you have 10 such columns?

Comment: @RonakShah Okay I fixed it. Thanks for the heads up.